# Searching for in one field or another depending on which I pass in?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a Stored Procedures in sql server 2008.
I need to get user (all the columns in dbo.UserDetails) by UserId (the user id comes from another Table (dbo.UserSubjects)) and UserName (that comes from dbo.UserDetails).
i will always have UserID but not always have UserName.

So now for my question how can I write a Stored Procedures that if 
the UserName Is empty the query will search only by UserId and if UserName is not empty
the query will search  with UserId and UserName

So far I have written:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserBySubjectID](@ID int = NULL, @Name string)
AS
SET     NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN   TRY
    IF  @ID IS NULL
            RAISERROR   400001 'User with given Subject ID does not exist'

ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT  UD.*                
    FROM    dbo.UserDetails UD , dbo.UserSubjects US
    WHERE   US.UserID = UD.UserID and US.SubjectID = @ID and UD.UserName = @Name 

    IF  @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RAISERROR   400001 'User with given ID does not exist'
END
RETURN  0
END     TRY
BEGIN   CATCH
    EXEC    dbo.GetErrorInfo
    RETURN  1
END     CATCH
```

Comment: Can an ID have multiple user names?

Comment: Also you should go through and try to accept some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another IF statement to your code to check if `@Name` is NULL:

```
IF @Name IS NULL
BEGIN
 ...
 WHERE US.UserID = UD.UserID and US.SubjectID = @ID
 ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 ...
 WHERE  US.UserID = UD.UserID and US.SubjectID = @ID and UD.UserName = @Name 
 ...
```

It may feel like writing duplicate code, but it will perform much better than writing a dynamic `WHERE` clause.